# Initing and assigning a view controller in the applicationDelegate makes all the UI elements in the viewController be nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

In my ApplicationDelegate :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        initMembers()
        runTutorialIfNeeded()
        return true
    }

 func initMembers()
    {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        mainViewController = InlineMainViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

but this line causes a problem:

`mainViewController = InlineMainViewController()`

all the UIElements are nil when the code reaches `override func viewDidLoad() {`

If I comment this line `mainViewController = InlineMainViewController()` 
All Ui elements from the main storyboard are not nil

How can I fix this?
I need to save a reference of the main viewController in the applicationDelegate in order to interact with it when `messageMgr: GNSMessageManager` sends event.

Comment: Are you using storyboard or xib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialized the ViewController wrong. If you're using a storyboard then you should write this:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardFileName", bundle: nil)
    mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("your_VC_ID")
    window.rootViewController = mainViewController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

If you're using NIB/XIB files then you should write this:

```
let mainViewController = YourViewController(nibName:"YourVCNibName", bundle:nil)
```

If you're just initializing it like InLineViewController(), there's no view attached to it and therefore everything is nil.

Comment: how do i find my "your_VC_ID" ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1fac47e1617d5a3d083bf5ed772e85ea See Storyboard ID, that's your VC id.

Comment: i see storyboard id in your image. not VC id ?

Comment: You have to insert the value yourself there. In your case you could/should write InLineMainViewController there and then write this in your AppDelegate: storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InLineMainViewController"). Is this more clear?

Comment: I thought that i can fill in only the real VC class name there. OK